# Access to razor view denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, azure

For the last few months of working on my MVC3 project I get a random access denied error on a razor view. In most cases I haven't made a single change to the view, and in the most recent case, the MVC project was unchanged too.

The mvc application is hosted in Azure, and the access denied errors only happen when running in the dev fabric. If I were to publish to the Cloud, the pages can be accessed.

I don't have any steps for reproducing this. And the only way I've found to fix it once it happens is to follow these steps:

1. Copy the markup from the affected page.
2. Delete the file
3. Create a new view with a slightly different name
4. Paste markup into new file
5. Rebuild
6. Rename file to old name

I've looked through IIS manager as the site is running, and it appears that the affected file exists and has the same permissions as other unaffected files.

What gives?

**UPDATE:** I just encountered this same problem with a WCF service (.svc) in the same solution (different project than the MVC proj though). This time the recreate-the-file trick didn't work. I checked the code out of subversion to a new working directory, and now it works again. This has to be something with IIS or Azure Compute Emulator.

The exception looks like this...

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'C:\Users\Brett\App\Working\trunk\Project.Web\Views\Assignments\_Assignment.cshtml'
>   is denied.
>
> Generated: Mon, 09 Jan 2012 20:55:00 GMT
>
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'C:\Users\Brett\App\Working\trunk\Project.Web\Views\Assignments\_Assignment.cshtml'
>   is denied.    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare
>   share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
>   secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.MapPathBasedVirtualFile.Open()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.OpenReader(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.EnsureGeneratedCode()
>   at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
>   at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider
>   buildProvider)

I truncated the stack trace, it was pretty large. If anyone wants the rest, I can provide it.

Comment: What does your AssignmentsController look like? Or whatever controller uses this page and makes it crash?

Comment: Are you accessing the local version through IIS or just hitting the run button and ending up at http://127.0.0.1:81/

Comment: I'm accessing it through the endpoint hosted in azure dev fabric.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your app off your local IIS instead of VS developer server.

You need to make sure you have IIS_IUSRS to have read & execute permission on the file.